# Scanning numbers from an array

Tags: c, arrays, fopen

So I created an dynamic array in C. The array contains only numbers. How can I scan the 1D array I created to print how many numbers are greater than the last one in the array? I created the code for scanning the file only, which is the following:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <limits.h> 
int process( FILE *f ) { 

int a, b; 
static int total = 1;                       

if ( f == 0 ) return 0; 
if ( fscanf( f, "%d", &a ) != 1 ) return INT_MIN; 
if ( (b= check_file ( f )) == INT_MIN ) return a; 
if ( a > b )  
{total++; return printf( "%d > %d and total now is %d\n", a, b, total ), a; }
return b;
} 
int main( void ) { 
    FILE *fp= fopen( "xxx.txt", "r" ); 
    process( fp ); 
    fclose( fp ); 

    return 0; 
}
```

Can I make the same with the array? How can I do that? Which commands should I use?

Dynamic array:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main () 
{ 
  int t_size;

  FILE * fp;                                                                        
        fp = fopen ("xxx.txt", "r");

        fscanf(fp, "%d", &t_size); 
        printf("Create a size of %d array\n", t_size);

        int* my_array = NULL; 
        my_array = malloc(t_size*sizeof(*my_array));

        if (my_array==NULL) {
        printf("Error allocating memory!\n"); //print an error message
        return 1; //return with failure
        getchar();
        }
        int i =0;
        for ( i = 0; i < t_size; i++ )
        {
        fscanf(fp, "%d",&my_array[i]);
        }

        //if all is working smoothly...
        printf("All up and running! Array created! :D\n");
        for(i = 0; i < t_size; i++ )
        {
        printf(" %d : %d\n", i, my_array[i]);
        }
        getchar();

        free(my_array);
}
```

Comment: I reversed your edit. Please don't delete the contents of your question once you got the problem solved. This is bad for the community. Consider accepting an answer, or write one yourself and then accept it - just do something that shows to future readers how to solve similar problems.

Comment: @Bill: I'm sorry to say but you could have considered that before asking *anywhere*  "on the web".

Answer (score 0):

You have to:

1. Add all the numbers from your file to the array (`int arr[N]`,  where `N` is number of the elements)
2. Find the value of the last element in the array (`arr[N-1]`)
3. Go through the array and count how many are greater then the last one.

Comment: I suggest starting with a course on I/O in C, as well as how to handle an `int` array.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

int process( int *array, int *endp) { 
    int a, b; 
    if ( array == 0 ) return 0; 
    if ( array == endp ) return INT_MIN;
    else a = *array++; 
    if ( (b= process( array, endp )) == INT_MIN ) return a; 
    if ( a > b ) return printf( "%d > %d\n", a, b ), a; 
    return b; 
} 
int main( void ) { 
    int array[] = { 4, 3, 2, 1};
    int t_size = 4;

    process(array, array + t_size);

    return 0; 
}
```